# Upgrade to version Frame v2

Tags: substrate

I would like to contribute to substrate recipes by upgrading pallets to frame v2 but there is no documentation explaining how to upgrade a pallet from v1 to v2.

Any suggestion? Doc? Tutoria?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's documentation on upgrading substrate but it's tucked away in the docs subdirectory:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docs/Upgrading-2.0-to-3.0.md